# Is it ok to uncheck "Keep Alive" checkbox in samplers? I'm getting "443 failed to respond" error

Tags: http, jmeter, keep-alive

Need a little help here. I'm doing a load test for a mobile app.

Im getting this "Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException/Non HTTP response message: {{myserver}}:443 failed to respond" errors randomly with low/medium/high loads.

I found that unchecking the "Keep-Alive" checkbox solves the issue. But, Is it ok to disable this "Keep-alive" option? What's the use of it actually? Is there any other way to solve the above issue? I need to find if this is a server-side error or JMeter error.

Jmeter version - 5.4.1

The below test was executed with "Keep-Alive" = true

[Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYfjU.png)

[Request defaults data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lws3m.png)

Comment: Apache Jmeter 5.4.1

Answer (score 0):

We don't know. What we know is that the checkbox is responsible for [Connection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header value

- If you tick it - JMeter sends `Connection: keep-alive` header indicating that the client (browser or in your case JMeter) would like to keep the connection open. Establishing a connection is an "expensive" process so it makes sense to do it once and then send requests/receive responses over the existing connection
- If you untick it - JMeter sends `Connection: close` header indicating that the client would like to close the connection after receiving the response

It's quite obvious that a [well-behaved JMeter web test should "behave" like a real browser](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser) hence I would recommend using your [browser developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) and seeing what is the value of the aforementioned `Connection` header for the real browser and configure JMeter to behave exactly in the same manner.

[image]